# Row uniqueness in Cassandra table with PRIMARY KEY (hash, created)

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to create a table containing 2 columns, one of which is a unique hash and another is the timestamp of when the row was created.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace.table (
    account varchar,
    hash varchar,
    lt bigint,
    created timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (hash, created)
)  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

I want the table to be ordered by the `created` field but unique on only the `hash` field.
I believe the uniqueness is currently checked as a union of both the fields; and a new row is only considered a duplicate if it has the same value for both of the fields.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @ErickRamirez how would I do what I described? it's currently checking duplicates with both fields but I want it to be checked only on the `hash` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is not possible.

To give you a bit of background, each `hash` (partition key) uniquely identifies each partition in the table. Since your schema has a compound primary key (partition key + clustering key), each partition in your table has one or more rows of `created`). The whole primary key therefore identifies each unique row in the partition.

It isn't possible at all for just the partition key `hash` to be the unique identifier for the a row. If that's what you want, you need to model your data differently with:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts_by_hash (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (hash)
)
```

Ultimately, you need to go back to the primary principle of data modelling in Cassandra and that is you need to design tables based on the application queries. Cheers!